# Android Material Date Picker Not Looking Right

Tags: java, android

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYCkM.png)

My theme for the xml is:

```
<style name="Theme.A.MaterialComponents" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@drawable/rounded_dialog_bg</item>
    </style>
```

My theme for the Material Date Picker is:

```
<style name="Theme.A.CustomMaterialDatePicker" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

The code creating this Material Date Picker is:

```
MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
          .setTitleText("Select Date").setTheme(R.style.Theme_SchoolProject_CustomMaterialDatePicker)
          .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()).build();
materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis((Long) selection);

                        SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
                        String goal = outFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                        dueDateView.setHint(goal);
                    }
                });

                materialDatePicker.addOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        //TODO Respond to dismiss events.
                    }
                });

                materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePickerDialog");
```

I tried changing the material date picker theme parent to something else instead of  "Theme.MaterialComponents" but it always gave me this error:

`MaterialCalendar requires a value for the com.example.A:attr/materialCalendarStyle attribute to be set in your app theme. You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`

Even if I changed it to Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog or something like that.

I tried changing the theme parent to Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar but it gave me the same error.
How can I fix it?